# publish fails to send message

Tags: ros, c++, jointtrajectory, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

i'm writing a simple c++ code where i publish an message of type trajectory_msgs::JointTrajector. When i execute the code, everything works well except the moment of publishing the message. So what i understood is that my publisher.publish(msg); is having problem, is this my problem or is this type of message impossible to send?

heres my code:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include "trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectory.h"
#include "trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectoryPoint.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "trajectory_test_node");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  
  ros::Publisher r_arm_comand_publisher = nh.advertise<trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectory>("/signbot/r_arm_controller/command", 1000);

   /// Create a JointTrajectory with all positions set to zero, and command the arm.
   if(ros::ok())
   {
     // Create a message to send.
     trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectory msg;

     // Fill the names of the joints to be controlled.
     msg.joint_names.clear();
     msg.joint_names.push_back("r_shoulder_joint");
     msg.joint_names.push_back("r_top_arm_joint");
     msg.joint_names.push_back("r_elbow_joint");
     msg.joint_names.push_back("r_wrist_joint");
     // Create one point in the trajectory.
     msg.points.resize(1);
     // Resize the vector to the same length as the joint names.
     // Values are initialized to 0.
     msg.points[0].positions.resize(msg.joint_names.size(), 0.0);
     // How long to take getting to the point (floating point seconds).
     msg.points[0].time_from_start = ros::Duration(0.0001);

     ROS_INFO_STREAM ("Sending command:\n" << msg);
     r_arm_comand_publisher.publish(msg);
  }
 return 0;
}
```

Hope you can help :-)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266361/publish-fails-to-send-message/) by [FábioBarbosa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29070/f%C3%A1biobarbosa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 137 on 2017-07-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i found the solution. I dont known why but ros::Duration(3).sleep(); doesnt help, So, i use loop_rate.sleep();. Like:

```
  ros::Rate loop_rate(0.2);
  ...
  ....
  r_arm_comand_publisher.publish(msg);

  ros::spinOnce();
  loop_rate.sleep();
```

in this way i get everything working well.

Thanks for all the help

---

Originally posted by [FábioBarbosa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29070/f%C3%A1biobarbosa/) with karma: 137 on 2017-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> is this my problem or is this type of message impossible to send?

no, not at all, but you don't seem to give ROS any opportunity to properly send it out to your subscribers, as your program immediately exits after your call to `publish(..)`.

That won't work, as all the infrastructure will be teared down before the middleware has had time to process everything.

Add a sleep or delay before your `return 0` and things will probably work (provided there are no other problems with your code).

---

Know that pub/sub is an asynchronous communication system. If you require confirmation or guaranteed delivery, use services.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-07-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FábioBarbosa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29070/f%C3%A1biobarbosa/) on 2017-07-14**:
what you are saying is to wirte something like this: ros::Duration(10).sleep(); before return 0;?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-14**:
Yes, that would be one way to do it.

**Comment by [FábioBarbosa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29070/f%C3%A1biobarbosa/) on 2017-07-14**:
try that, didnt work :S